# AngularJS module creation inside RequireJS define with dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angular-ui-router

I'm having an issue creating an AngularJS module inside a RequireJS define method.

When I make reference to the ui-router module that I need, Angular tells me:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

This only happens if I define `uiRouter` in the requireJS dependency list.

Here's my code:

```
require.config({
    paths : {
        'angular' : "/script/lib/angular",
        'uiRouter' :"/script/lib/angular-ui-router",

    },
    shim : {
        'angular': {
            exports : 'angular'
        },
        'uiRouter' : {
            deps : ['angular']
        }
    }

});

define(['angular', 'uiRouter'], function (angular) {
    var module = angular.module('myApp', []);
});
```

If I take `uiRouter` out of the define dependency array, everything works as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your requirejs version?

Comment: Angular: v1.3.0-rc.4

Comment: I edited my asnwer also where is your return statement?

Comment: Thanks @Blackunknown but creating the require module as a named module doesn't help. There's no return statement, there doesn't need to be one.

Comment: Sorry @KhanhTO, you asked about the requireJS version which is: 2.1.15

Comment: @JamieDixon Have you tried the following: var module = angular.module('myApp', ['uiRouter']);

Comment: Whats the stack trace below the error you have pasted. Your code looks ok to me

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the ui.router to your module.

```
define(['angular', 'uiRouter'], function (angular) {
    var module = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
});
```

EDIT: I added the following:

```
define('myApp', ['angular', 'uiRouter'], function (angular) {
    var module = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
});
```

Comment: I was just adding the edit saying although it might not fix your issue. :P Lets see what else there is.